# javascript for-loop repeating last iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to crop-resize n display an image on client-browser using JS. I am able to do so except that my text loop is wrong. You can see in the image below that it is repeating the last iteration. My image loop works fine though. `Hint` - First filename text is supposed to be `black.jpg`.

[image]

Am unable to solve the issue after having tried for several hours. Given below is a trimmed version of the code. If needed here is the [complete version](https://codetidy.com/8294/) of the script. Please help, I am still learning.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="prevCrop()" multiple> 
<ul id="listWrapper"></ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function prevCrop() {
    var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i]; 
        var fileSize = Math.floor(file.size/1024);
        var info = file.name + " " + fileSize + " KB : iteration number - " + i;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        if (reader != null) {
        reader.onload = GetThumbnail;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }           
    }


    function GetThumbnail(e) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = e.target.result;
        newImage.onload = cropResize; 

        function cropResize() {
            canvas.width = 70;
            canvas.height = 70;
            ### more codes here that handles image   ###

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
            var thumbList = document.createElement('div');
            thumbList.setAttribute('class', 'tlistClass');  
            var nImg = document.createElement('img'); 
            nImg.src = dataURL;     
            var infoSpan = document.createElement('span');                      
            infoSpan.innerHTML = info;          
            var handle = document.getElementById("listWrapper").appendChild(thumbList);
            handle.appendChild(nImg);
            handle.appendChild(infoSpan);   
        }               
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `onload` callback function is triggered asynchronously, so after your code has already ended. At that time `info` has the string that was assigned to it in the last iteration. Only then the `onload` events are fired, resulting in the different calls of `GetThumbnail`, which all will see the same value for `info`.

Instead bind the value of `info` to the callback function like this:

```
    reader.onload = GetThumbnail.bind(null, info);
```

...and define the corresponding parameter for it in the `GetThumbnail` function:

```
function GetThumbnail(info, e) {
```

That way every call of that function will posses of the proper value for `info`.

Comment: Thank you, that solves it. I have so [much to learn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/19323214#19323214)